# Unit Test Vue Component Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue-component, vue.js

I have created vue components using this structure.

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>A custom component!</div>'
})
```

I would like to test this using karma and jasmine or jasmine rails gem. I can't figure out how to test the component. In all the examples on the docs they use a requirejs module way of testing. I use the global component way of creating components.

These are the examples from the docs.

```
<template>
  <span>{{ message }}</span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        message: 'hello!'
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.message = 'bye!'
    }
  }
</script>

// Import Vue and the component being tested
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from 'path/to/MyComponent.vue'

// Here are some Jasmine 2.0 tests, though you can
// use any test runner / assertion library combo you prefer

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  // Inspect the raw component options
  it('has a created hook', () => {
    expect(typeof MyComponent.created).toBe('function')
  })
  // Evaluate the results of functions in
  // the raw component options
  it('sets the correct default data', () => {
    expect(typeof MyComponent.data).toBe('function')
    const defaultData = MyComponent.data()
    expect(defaultData.message).toBe('hello!')
  })
  // Inspect the component instance on mount
  it('correctly sets the message when created', () => {
    const vm = new Vue(MyComponent).$mount()
    expect(vm.message).toBe('bye!')
  })
  // Mount an instance and inspect the render output
  it('renders the correct message', () => {
    const Ctor = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
    const vm = new Ctor().$mount()
    expect(vm.$el.textContent).toBe('bye!')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`import foo from 'bar';` and `var foo = require('bar');` does the same thing, making `foo` available as a variable in the current file. In the test example, `MyComponent` is the imported vue component instance, which can also be achieved with `MyComponent = Vue.component(...);` in the current file. So if your test is in the same file, just use the `MyComponent` variable, if not, you'll need to export `MyComponent` first with `module.exports = MyComponent` or `export default MyComponent`. These exports assume `MyComponent` is the only thing you want to export, if you want to export multiple variables, checkout the docs: http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1 https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export